# CheckBalance.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `stack<char>::stack()'

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am creating my assignment for stack structure and checking the expression for correctness and on compile the errors are 
i have read other question but can`t find solution.i have written all constructors and destructors

```
E:\Smester 4\Data Structure and Algoritham\Assignments\Assignment7\CheckBalance.o   CheckBalance.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `stack<char>::stack()'
E:\Smester 4\Data Structure and Algoritham\Assignments\Assignment7\CheckBalance.o   CheckBalance.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `stack<char>::push(char)'
E:\Smester 4\Data Structure and Algoritham\Assignments\Assignment7\CheckBalance.o   CheckBalance.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `stack<char>::pop()'
```

my program files are ( constructors )

in stack.h

```
public:
stack();
 private:
int counter;
node<T>* last;
```

in stack.cpp

```
 template<class T>
 stack<T>::stack(){
    last = 0;
    counter = 0;
 }
```

in CheckBalance.h

```
  public:
  CheckBalance();
  private:
  stack<char>* mystack ;
```

in CheckBalance.cpp

```
 CheckBalance::CheckBalance()
 {
     mystack= new stack<char>();
 }
```

Comment: #ifndef node_h    
#define node_h      
template<class T>     
class node{     
public:        
 node(T);      
 ~node();       
 T getData();         
 void setData(T);       
 node<T>* getPrePtr();       
 void setPrePtr(node<T>*);        
private:           
 T data;        
 node* prePtr;     
};   
#endif

Comment: include #include <stack>

Comment: `undefined reference to stack<char>::pop()` etc. nowhere in the code you show do you use, declare or define `pop`. Have you shown all relevant code?

Comment: also note that if `stack` is a template, separate compilation wont work, you need to put all the code in the header.

Comment: @Spartacus: no, this implements a `stack` of its own, it does not use `std::stack`

Comment: @ShakeeL put template code's implementation in header file.

Comment: I hava implemented all functions

Comment: It works by putting all code in stack header.Thanks